# Does a stack overflow error trigger a core dump and is it useful if it does?

Tags: c++, gdb, stack-overflow

I'm having a heck of a time finding an answer to this because of "Stack Overflow"'s site name.  Everything online references stackoverflow.com and whatever words I search on instead! **wah!**

**My question is:**

1. Does a stack overflow error (say from infinite recursion) cause a core dump?
2. Is the core dump useful if it does generate one, or would GDB see it as jibberish?

Comment: It depends... I ahve seen some stack flows where the stack got trashed and the debugger could not make heads from tails (I.e. all the backtrack showed was question marks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does assuming you've got your dump setup for it.  And yes, it's very useful, because at the very least it can tell you just where the stack overflowed.

Of course, sometimes the dump unrolls the stack as

```
foo
foo
foo
 .
 .
 .
```

for a very large number of `foo`s, but then you add breakpoints or print statements to see what was happening just before the stack dump.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think that **no error** can be/is triggered by the system for a stack overflow.</del>

<del>The stack is a memory buffer, which *can* be allocated by users (initial address and size). So the only damage that are created by **stack overflows** are the usual **buffer overflows**.</del>

<del>For instance, is your memory looks like</del>

```
|-----------------------|
|          ...          |
| ... valuable data ... | 
|          ...          |
|-----------------------|
|          ...     ^    |
|          ...     |    |
|          stack   |    | 
|-----------------------|
```

<del>then a stackoverflow will wipe out your data.
It's also obviously implementation and architecture dependent, for instance if debug information were at this place (for instance, thread details are stored in memory), then it would mess up the debugger behavior.</del>

**<edit>** as mentioned by @MSalters, this part is not (entirely ?) true, which means that the kernel ensures that the stack stays in its boundaries. In this case, There should be nothing preventing debuggers from reading stackoverflow coredumps.**</edit>**

Playing with GDB Python can allow you to stop the execution in the middle of the overflow, with something like: (untested)

```
FCT_NAME = "my_function" 
MAX_DEPTH = 100 
class StackOverflowBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
  def stop(self):
    frame = gdb.newest_frame()
    depth = 0
    while frame is not None:
      frame = frame.older()
      depth += 1
    # stop only if we're deep enough
    return depth > MAX_DEPTH

bp = StackOverflowBreakpoint(FCT_NAME)
bp.silent = True
```

`StackOverflowBreakpoint.stop` will be called each time the function is triggered, but GDB will stop the execution only when a stackoverflow condition is detected.

Comment: If you set a stack yourself, you're responsible for its protection (see pthread_attr_setguardsize())[http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_getguardsize.3.html] . Your example memory layout therefore is already buggy, even before a stack overflow.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't know that, I've updated the answer. However, the example is not buggy, data *can* be located right after a (user-defined) memory stack

Comment: I think we're reading the specs differently then. As I read it, the non-buggy setup for a user-defined stack is `|stack-->|guard|valuable_data|`. On stack overflow, the guard area will trigger a `SEGFAULT` in the kernel and it will then deal with the fallout.

Comment: @MSalters The specs say that the guard may have a size of 0, that is, no guard, which is not a buggy situation. And there are different ways to create a new stack, like [sigaltstack](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sigaltstack+2) where, according to the example, you have to *manually* create your guards. (`sigaltstack` is used for instance for user-level thread libraries)

Comment: Indeed, I said that "you are responsible for the protection" [against stack overflow]. A guard page is one valid implementation (whether set up manually or automatic), but a VM that proves an upper bound to stack usage is another valid method to protect against stack overflow.